# how to create website thumb nail from URL in C#.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, thumbnails, utility

Is it any way to create thumbnail image from any website URL? 
When I write any URL Link into textbox then I have show thumbnail of entered URL.

How can I achieve in C#.net.. suggest me.