# Can Webkit .net instantiate a browser instance with no form interface?

Tags: c#, webkit, webkit.net

Or, for that matter, is there another productive way to access Webkit in C# than Webkit.net? I'm trying to create a website thumbnail generator using Webkit in a web service. It's a piece of cake to do with a WinForms host for the control, but I can't seem to find the pure library interface for it...

TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create website thumb nail from URL in C#.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026107/how-to-create-website-thumb-nail-from-url-in-c-net)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use webkit for this?

Comment: @Chris - I've already got it working with IE9 and I want to implement Webkit and Gecko alternatives. This is relatively trivial to do with IE9.

Comment: @Nick - been there, got the t-shirt, cut the sleeves off, washed the car with it. Now I'm trying to do it with Webkit.